# How do I use the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given hermitian matrices $H$ and $S$.
Given the BCS formula

$e^{X} e^{Y}=e^{Z}$

where:
$Z=X+Y+\frac{1}{2}[X, Y]+\frac{1}{12}[X,[X, Y]]-\frac{1}{12}[Y,[X, Y]]+\cdots$

How do I show the expansion of $H'$ in terms of commutators?

$H^{\prime}=e^{S} H e^{-S}$

$H^{\prime}=H +\left[S, H\right]+\frac{1}{2}[S,[S, H]]+\ldots$

Comment: Why is it important to split $H$ into $H_0 +V$? It looks like it just makes the bookkeeping more difficult.

Comment: You are right, I removed it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding $e^S$ into the definition of matrix exponential $e^S=1+S+\frac{S^2}{2!}\dots$
will give you the form of $H'=H+[S, H]+\frac{1}{2}[S,[S, H]]+\ldots$. Not sure how this is related to the BCS formula though.